# Bluetooth issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I'm trying to use the built-in bluetooth on my Lenovo X140e but even though I'm able to turn it on, it never locates any devices I try to pair with it. I've tried with a Dualshock controller and my android phone, but no luck. The most common error I get when seeing the terminal output is "D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use," but I'm not sure what that means or how to fix it, or if it's even the root of the problem.

```
matberron@thinkpad:~$ sudo bluetoothd -d -n
[sudo] password for matberron: 
bluetoothd[7278]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
bluetoothd[7278]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing main.conf
bluetoothd[7278]: src/main.c:parse_config() discovto=0
bluetoothd[7278]: src/main.c:parse_config() pairto=0
bluetoothd[7278]: src/main.c:parse_config() pageto=8192
bluetoothd[7278]: src/main.c:parse_config() auto_to=60
bluetoothd[7278]: src/main.c:parse_config() name=%h-%d
bluetoothd[7278]: src/main.c:parse_config() class=0x000100
bluetoothd[7278]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DeviceID'
D-Bus setup failed: Name already in use
bluetoothd[7278]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

Any advice would be appreciated, and let me know if you need any other info on my end. Thank you!